# Conan: Is there any way to manage profiles like a package

Tags: c++, conan

As far as I understand the Conan documentation, a Profile is something that must be managed manually by the user. Is this correct?

It would be neat if profiles and toolchains could be pushed/pulled like regular packages. I understand that the toolchain itself can be pushed as a tool-package (build_requires), but then you still need the profile to fetch and use the toolchain package.

Is there no other option than to simply have a git repository for example, with an organization's profiles, and then install them manually when you need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Conan [config](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/config.html) command. Conan config is not only about `conan.conf` file.

With [conan config install](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/config.html#conan-config-install), you can import external profiles and install directly to your Conan cache folder.

As example, you can use [Bincrafters' profiles](https://github.com/bincrafters/bincrafters-config) available on Github. As you can see, it's a simple git repository with a folder and some profiles.

You can do the same for your company, create an internal git repository and share most regular profiles used by them.

Comment: While this method provides some use of GIT the profiles you install are copied into the .conan/profiles folder as a one-off - hence not managed by git - and therefore changes are not tracked and are therefore difficult to keep track of when they need to go back into GIT. It also leaves behind stuff you delete from GIT - hence you risk some users use deleted profiles, which causes problems.
It would be nice with a proper git integration.

Comment: @Casper could you please, file an issue to Conan directly asking for this new feature: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues